# Epileptic seizure alarm plus phone call & SMS Android software

Tags: android, monitoring, phone, health, input-devices

I am looking for an Android application that uses the accelerometer sensor in the mobile phone, perhaps with a few software tags attached to the body and communicating with the phone, for detecting epileptic seizures.

The software would work as follows: the phone stays in a designated cushioned pocket and if the person falls the accelerometer sensor will have detected that the phone in the pocket has fallen onto the floor without breaking, and initiate a simultaneous phone call and SMS to a designated person on the ICE list.

If the phone is taken out of the pocket a software tag on the pocket can somehow compute the distance between the pocket and the phone, and software on the phone detects whether some "non-background" app is in use and has not been idle. The phone and the pocket tag communicate via Bluetooth. So, if the person has a seizure while the phone id's out the person falls and the phone falls with the pocket even when the phone is out the the same alarm mechanism triggers. The combined communication triggers the phone call plus SMS.

If the person with risk of epileptic seizure decides to do things like skiing or doing pushups then this mechanism can be calibrated so that the system can detect the difference between just a normal body reconfiguration/movement/action and a fall triggered by an epileptic seizure.

Comment: [A quick check](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=epileptic%20alarm) has 2 candidates listed on top where the first sound promising: [EpSyDet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sample.epislepsysd): *Our system combines the power of new devices such as MIO ALPHA watch to detect epileptic seizures.* Seems like worth a look – though its last update was in 5/2015.

Comment: Thank you so much Izzy. I've watched the video and it seems great (plus it has a 5-star rating).

Comment: Anytime, Jack! Finding Android apps is my speciality (see [my website](https://android.izzysoft.de/)). If you gave this app a try and find it worth recommending, feel encouraged to self-answer your question with it. I can't do that, as I've never used it and neither can really evaluate or judge it.

Comment: Thank you Izzy for your help. To try the app I need a wristwatch though. It would be good if the app included a special test mode that you could use to simulate pulse and data transmission from the wristwatch to the device. That way people could test it, eg. prior to purchasing the Bluetooth wristwatch. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you find an alternative (or even if), you could contact the dev and ask for that. The description of the app says they use that wristwatch stuff *in addition* to the on-device accel things, so there should be a way to test one without the other – and to demonstrate how the additional equipment would improve things.

Comment: Yeah, this means also being able to test the wristwatch without the phone. Well said, and as always, thanks for letting me know about this app. :-)